# $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{16}\right)$ not working on Ti-89

Tags: trigonometry, calculator

If I ask TI-89 to evaluate a special angle like $\displaystyle \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$ or $\displaystyle \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$  I get back nice fractional results.  But if I ask for something like $\displaystyle \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{16}\right)$  it just spits "$\displaystyle \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{16}\right)$ " back at me.  Is there a way to tell it to return the decimal value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know for sure, but usually I believe ctrl + equals works.

Comment: worked, thanks.  Only it is called "ENTER", not equals.  And apparently "ctrl" looks like a little yellow diamond.  I want to go back to Python.

Comment: @MK I know the feeling. If only the Ti could use numpy